# how to convert a .execute to just display right away on textview instead

Tags: java, android, json

adminpage.java

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dataList);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rf);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // new JSONTask().execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoItem.txt");
            new JSONTask().execute("https://jsonparsingdemo-cec5b.firebaseapp.com/jsonData/moviesDemoList.txt");

        }
    });

}
 public static class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            String finalJson = buffer.toString();

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(finalJson);
            JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("movies");

            StringBuffer finalBufferedData = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String movieName = finalObject.getString("movie");
                int year = finalObject.getInt("year");
                finalBufferedData.append(movieName + " - " + year + "\n");
            }
            //JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);


            return finalBufferedData.toString();

            //return buffer.toString();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        mTextView.setText(result);


    }


}
```

So base on this what i can conclude is.

1) JSONTASK will take the url and break them in to different string and link them together and return finalBufferedData.toString();

2) The onPostExecute will take the result and set it to mTextView.

3) onclicklistener will run the function and perform step 2 and display.

Question!

- I don't see anywhere in the code that call the function `onPostExecute(String result)` <-- what is the result?? is it the return `finalBufferedData.toString()`?
- I am running the same  function in another activity, how do i display in `TextView` without the `onClicklistener` to execute it.

Comment: @SRBbans thanks for the first answer. the second part can i have an example. because they are from different activity. the current method i done was not very right, i copy the same chunk of codes to another activity and call from there... it still works just not ideal

Comment: dude.. what is the problem in writing the code in second activity.. ?

Comment: its a duplication of codes right? isnt it bad writing

Comment: duplication of code is a bad thing .. i agree...  but here you have two acivities and two views... and only one of them can be on screen at a time. .. if you have the same data then just pass that though the `Bundle` and `intent` to your second activity and get it in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1**. Yes.. it is the return value(finalBufferedData.toString()).It is the output (result/return) of doInBackground method.

**2**. Call in onCreate or onResume for executing without onClick. **eg:-**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

// put the AsyncTask call here
```